# Expression Engine Preventing additional entries by a single member

Tags: forms, expressionengine, member, safecracker

I have a safe cracker form that allows a logged in member to submit an entry (a vote, actually). When they submit their vote, I want to prevent them from ever being able to submit an entry to this channel again. Is that possible? If so, how? Something automatic that either sets a member variable or searches some field to see if a member has submitted or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just wrap something like this

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='votes' author_id='{logged_in_member_id}' dynamic='off'}
  {if total_results == 0}
    {!-- allow a new entry --}
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

around some or all of you voting form?

Comment: Actually, that's pretty smart, yeah. I would be using a channel entries tag within a channel entries tag within a safecracker tag, so it would require a lot of embeds, but I think it would work. Thanks!

Comment: instead of wrapping that around an entry form, i'ld suggest  
if total_results > 0 redirect="already_voted_template"

Comment: for some reason that syntax isn't working for me. Nothing displays within the channel entries tag (let alone the conditional). Am I missing something?

Comment: @mheavers:  sorry, didn't realize you already had a `channel:entries` loop.  If the embeds are too ugly, you could likely cookup some kind of simple `has_voted` plugin without breaking your brain.

Comment: you're using the correct channel, of course?  I just made one up.

Comment: Yeah - I changed the channel. Anyway, sounds like the right solution. I'll try to set up a blank template and see if it works